# How to Push a new classes to Remote Git Repository?

Tags: git, eclipse, github

I have a project on Github. I download it, I opened it using Eclipse, and I added some classes to this project.

I created a local repository and new branch. Then, I did `Team>> Share Project` to new branch. The project appear in `working Tree folder on Git Explorer`.

The problem is when I am trying to push the changes to remote repository on Github it does not work.

I am trying to do `Add to Index`, but this option does not appear in the menu. I found all my changes appear in the `Working Tree folder` without `Add to Index`. However, nothing changed in staging area.

How could I push these changes to the remote repository?

Here some picture for the menu, working tree, and staging area.
[Team Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HqL7.jpg)
[Staging Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMRj6.png) [Working Tree Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqXCA.png)

Comment: The _Unstaged Changes_ shows the changed files. Moved them to _Staged Changes_ in order to commit them. The item in _Unstaged Changes_ looks weird and your Eclipse looks outdated.

Comment: I tried to move it to staged changes, but it does not moved in. How could I move it?

Comment: In your _Unstaged Changes_ the item looks like a Git repository, not like a file which is pretty weird. It also looks like your Eclipse is pretty old. Show what is show in the _Git Staging_ view in the current Eclipse after hitting the _Refresh_ button and tell which commits or branches exactly you want to push to which remote branch.

Comment: So, is my problem on Eclipse version?

Comment: Based on the information given, it's unclear if that's the only thing you did wrong.